# How to add a comment to the new method stub in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I let VS add a new method, it creates something like this:

```
    public void DoSomething(object withThis)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I want to add a comment and get something like this instead:

```
    public void DoSomething(object withThis)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); //TODO: Implement me!
    }
```

That way a new and not implemented method would automatically appear in the task list.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this particular scenario, but you could try editing the corresponding *.snippet file. It's called `MethodStub.snippet` and lies in `x:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\MethodStub.snippet` on my PC.

The result could look something like this:

```
<Code Language="csharp">
            <![CDATA[$signature$
{
    $end$throw new $Exception$(); //TODO: Implement me!
}]]>
</Code>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Is there an user directory, that could override this? I have found "GenerateConstructor - Constructor.snippet" containing a TODO-comment, but I'm not sure, how to trigger that snippet or ever seeing that comment. Or is this a missing in the Community Edition?

Comment: Can you check in Tools => Code Snippets manager if you can find the snippet there? It's under "Csharp"/Refactoring/Method Stub [Body|No Body] for me

Comment: They're all in the list, matching paths, seems ok, but the content isn't displayed, so I can't check what VS makes of it. I tried to import the changed snippet file, but no luck either. I can't remove a snippet, to re-add it.

Comment: It's also possible that this is handled by a (build-in) Roslyn code fix, in which case I'm not sure it's possible to change it at all.